# How to make alias with administrator privileges applescript

Tags: permissions, applescript

My script is working as intended and is creating my alias folder perfectly except everytime it prompts me to type in my computers password because it needs administrator privileges.  Applescript wont allow me to add the code to give administrator privileges so I am stumped as to what to do.  The code below works but requires my password to complete

```
make new alias at myLocation to mySource
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
make new alias at myLocation to mySource password "myPassword" with administrator privileges
```

I have used code similar to this several times but for some reason it wont allow me to do so with creating an alias.  Anyone know what I need to do to automate this process instead of having to type in my password every single time?

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out that I could do this instead:

```
do shell script ("sudo ln -s " & quoted form of POSIX path of fullPathTitlesMedia & space & quoted form of POSIX path of parentMediaPath & "") password "password" with administrator privileges
```